# Reduce hive startup time for many hive -e invocations

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr, emr

I am invoking hive -e hundreds of times from the command line in this way:

```
cat hive_script.hql | parallel --gnu hive -e '{}'
```

where each line in hive_script.hql can run independently and in any order.

Are there any --hiveconf parameters that can reduce the start up time? The Apache web page seems to suggest there might be at

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution

```
"This is frustrating as Hive becomes closely coupled with scripting languages. The Hive startup time of a couple seconds is non-trivial when doing thousands of manipulations such as multiple hive -e invocations."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't speed hive -e up but you can put multiple queries in one script.

If that doesn't work you will need to look at HiveServer2 and invoking queries from a JDBC client.

Comment: My goal is to have several apps running simultaneously, I have found using gnu parallel gave me large speed ups over a script. Can you straightforwardly submit multiple jobs to run simultaneously from a jdbc client running on the emr master node?